# Is there a Public Library that lends English Audiobooks?

Tags: speech, internet, reading

In germany there are now a plethora of public libraries where I can borrow Audiobooks. I can search and download DRM protected files and can use them for a couple of days or weeks before they get invalidated automatically.

Alas, there are (almost) only german ones. But I am much more interested in **english Audiobooks**. There must be a **online accessible public library** somewhere where I can borrow english audiobooks for a fee, mustn't it?

Comment: From libraries, I haven't heard of doing that for -free- in the US. But "borrow for a fee"? That sounds like, in other domains, renting, but for audio online it sounds like ... buying? podcast, audiobook, whatever, you're just buying it.

Comment: Renting, right. In many german public libraries this is now possible with DRM protected audio files. You can only use them for some days. At my place its 2 weeks.

Comment: Hi Towi- Yes, many US libraries have this service - usually with free borrowing for a limited time but because of copyright laws you have to be a member of the library - i.e. fairly local. You also have to have a specific device.

Comment: The public library here (in the US) does have that service, so I guess Mitch doesn't have much experience.  But (as noted) you have to live in the local area (where the taxes supporting the library are collected) to participate.

Comment: @Marcus_33: That's what I thought -- I did not check, but I guess one has to be a local resident at our public library, too.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a Public Library, but you can might a few audiobooks on Wikicommons:

- http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Spoken_Wikisource_-_English
- http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Audiobooks

There are also many [spoken Wikipedia articles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aSpoken_articles).

As Born2Smile tipped me, the best collection of audio books is probably at Project Gutenberg:

- http://www.gutenberg.org/browse/categories/1

Comment: also gutenberg.org has audiobooks